# Why is my cron task working in command line, but not in PLESK?

Tags: php, cron, plesk

I want to setup a cronjob that worked perfectly under PLESK 9 on another dedicated server, but can't get it to work in my new dedicated server under PLESK 10. I just can't figure out why.

Some info: I have PHP running as Apache module and:

***whereis php*** says: ***php: usr/bin/php***

And

***usr/bin/php -q /var/pathtocronjob***

works perfectly in command line.
However, when I set this up in PLESK in a "Scheduled task" it just says

***-: /usr/bin/php: No such file or directory***

I've searched for anything that could help me out, but just can't find any help.
Anyone knows why this isn't working and of course... How to fix this?

Comment: Try only php instead of the full path, maybe Plesk has an internal mapping for it...

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure to include the first slash `/`.

You should replace:

```
usr/bin/php -q /var/pathtocronjob
```

with

```
/usr/bin/php -q /var/pathtocronjob
```

Comment: And in case this doesn't work, like in my case, then the path to php is not good. So what you need to do then is call `which php`, this command will tell you the correct path to php.

Answer (score 2):

May be some kind of chrooted shell for cron tasks? Look at [Admin guide](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.1.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/index.htm?fileName=66791.htm)

Comment: According to my host, is "has something to do with permissions". Not really an answer I can do something with here, but at least it's a direction. Any suggestion where to look?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to access lower levels than the hosting/user is asigned on Plesk. This is to prevent user going outside there **var/www/vhosts/domein.tld** folders. This is a safety built in so user cant mess up the server with exploit commands, but just stay in their own sandbox.

Use the short **'php'** instead of **'usr/bin/php'**

For example magento reindexing command

```
    0 */3 * * * php -q httpdocs/shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

ps: 
a lot of the usual ssh commands wont work either in the crontab command field!